Degree-anticompatible orders are bounded below
For a monomial $\overline{x}^\alpha$, let $|\alpha| = \sum_{i = 1}^n \alpha_i$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n$.
A total ordering $>$ on monomials is degree-anticompatible if $|\alpha| \leq |\beta| \implies \overline{x}^\alpha \geq \overline{x}^\beta$.
Implictly, this also means that the ordering is compatible with multiplication ($\overline{x}^\beta \geq \overline{x}^\alpha \implies \overline{x}^{\beta + \gamma} \geq \overline{x}^{\alpha + \gamma}$ for all $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n$).
Exercise 4.4.3 of Cox, Little, and O'Shea's Using Algebraic Geometry is the following

Let $>$ be a degree-anticompatible ordering on either of the local rings $k[\overline{x}]_{\langle x_1, \ldots, x_n\rangle}$ or $k[[\overline{x}]]$.
Show that any nonempty set of monomials $\mathcal{S}$ is that bounded below has a smallest element.

This should be straightforward but after mulling over it for some time it's not coming to me. It also isn't clear why we need to consider just these local rings when we can have degree-anticompatible orderings over any polynomial ring.

What else does the ordering satisfy? With only this definition this is not clear. Also the exercise ask for something else: Let > be a degree-anticompatible order on one of our local rings R. Show that any nonempty set of monomials S that is bounded
below (meaning that there exists a monomial $x^\alpha$ such that $x^\beta \ge x^\alpha$ for all
$x^\beta \in S$) has a smallest element.

I added that the ordering is also a total ordering compatible with multiplication (although this is true for all semigroup orderings). Also what you wrote is equivalent to what I wrote, I just didn't define what bounded below meant because it's standard enough I thought.

I don't think what you have written is equivalent to the question in the book. The exercise assumes that the orders is bounded below and then asks for something else. Your question is different

Ok I see now. I completely misread the question. I will update the post again. I did not parse that exercise at all properly which is probably why I had trouble proving it.
